# Checking if a song still exists

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to determine whether a song still exists in the user's library before it is played. If a user deletes a song in their library, the following line of code acting on the MPMediaItem still yields a URL:

```
NSURL *songURL=[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
```

The `songURL` is in the form "ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=5050...etc." And then the following line crashes when called:

```
[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:nil];
```

I've tried using the following line to see if the song still exists, but it returns nil whether the song exists or not. I believe that is because it isn't compatible with the "ipod-library"-style URL.

```
NSData* songData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:songURL];
```

Any suggestions would be terrific. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try passing an `NSError` to your `initWithContentsOfURL:error:`. If you get an error back, you'll know the file doesn't exist (or was corrupt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell ahead of time, but AVAudioPlayer's initWithContentsOfURL will return nil and the error will be populated with an NSError if creating the player fails. Just check the return code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:fileTypeHint:error:

Comment: OK, too bad that it can't be checked ahead of time, but that solution works. Thanks for the reply!